# Create a Drupal 8 profile installer with a config export

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I want to create a Drupal 8 profile installer with a config export, to export regulary my config to push data modifications in git.

I tried this tutorial: https://www.valuebound.com/resources/blog/how-to-create-installation-profile-in-Drupal8
but it dont worked.
And i exported the configuration with `drupal config:export –remove-uuid --remove-config-hash`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see drush drush config-export and Sync

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/configuration-management/changing-the-storage-location-of-the-sync-directory

then when you make config changes run drush cex for commit the changes.

when updated form git you need to run drush cmi for imports the config

to watch out for you want to make sure your site uuids match: aka

drush cget system.site uuid
drush cset system.site uuid